# Heroku Automated Certificate Management for subdomains?

Tags: ssl, heroku, subdomain

I'm wondering if it's possible to use Heroku Automated Certificate Management for multiple subdomains. I think currently wildcard subdomains are not possible, but it seems specifically configured DNS subdomains might.

I'm just not sure the right way to do this, or if it's possible. I haven't found much clear info while googling.

Is this possible, and how would I do it (both on the DNS side and Heroku side)?

Comment: I believe you can for specific subdomains, but you are limited as to how many you can do. The tricky bit is setting up the DNS settings. Heroku side is basically the same as custom domains. The DNS side you likely need to use the subdomain name where you would normally use `www` or `*` depending on where you got the domain name.

Comment: @Nuclearman the part I'm pretty confident about is the DNS side, just not sure about the heroku side. There's probably some command to run...

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain @pixelearth